# How to create a pointer from contents of an int correctly?

Tags: c, pointers

Due to various restrictions, I have a method which only accepts an `int` argument. However, I want to pass this method a Struct.

So far, I have...

```
main(int argc, char* argv){
    Somestructure * name;
    //Name is malloced, things are put in it, etc.

    int address = (int) &name;
    method(address);
}

void method(int arg){
     Somestructure* thisStruct = (Somestructure*) arg;
     //Do stuff with thisStruct.
}
```

I thought this would assign `thisStruct` to point to the same struct as name in the main method, however when I attempt to use `thisStruct` in `method`, I get a Bus Error.
When I used this code...

```
    int structAddress = (int) &thisStruct;
    printf("[Method] Address : %d\n", structAddress);
```

It seems as though the addresses of `name` (inside `main`) and that of `thisStruct` (inside `method`) are different.

I'm a little new to C, but, does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

This code will only run on a 32-bit system, so I need not worry about any 64-bit int/address problems.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use a `void *` instead of `int`?

Comment: Aside from that, you are passing in *name, which is a pointer to 'nothing'.

Comment: Also make sure you actually allocate memory and make your pointer point to it before you dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you passed in `&name`, which is a pointer to a pointer to the struct. So, in the `method`, you are accessing the `Somestructure **` as if it was a `Somestructure *`.

Just pass in `(int)name`.

(P.S. the usual way to define a "generic argument" is to use `void *`.)

Comment: The careful user would first convert to `intptr_t` and then put some compile-time checks in place to make sure that the size fits.

Answer (score 3):

Since `name` is of type `Somestructure*`, the line

```
int address = (int) &name;
```

treats `address` as `Somestructure**`.  Using

```
int address = (int)name;
```

would do what you want.  Always assuming that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(Somestructure*)` of course.